# Thymeleaf template th:include strange behaviour

Tags: spring-boot, templates, web, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I have a Spring Boot WebApp; every webpage is build starting from a Thymeleaf template (`home.html`) that includes other templates (no fragments used).

I have a `resources/templates` structure like this one:

```
/templates
|
+- /one
   +- onefirst.html
+- /two
+- home.html
(...)
```

Inside `/one` I have only one template, `onefirst`.

If I use this code in `home.html`

```
<th:block th:insert="~{/one/one}">text</th:block>
```

it **unexpectedly works**.

And, of course, also this

```
<th:block th:insert="~{/one/onefirst}">text</th:block>
```

does. But,

```
<th:block th:insert="~{/one/onefirs}">text</th:block>
<th:block th:insert="~{/one/onefir}">text</th:block>
<th:block th:insert="~{/one/onefi}">text</th:block>
<th:block th:insert="~{/one/onef}">text</th:block>
```

don't.

I looked at documentation at

https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.1/usingthymeleaf.html#template-layout

and did not find anything that could explain this behaviour.

I would have expected only this form to work

```
<th:block th:insert="~{/one/onefirst}">text</th:block>
```